# Content loaded through js .load() doesn't load with url : http://www or www

Tags: javascript, html

I have an unusual situation.
I have loaded a part of my website with .load(), that only triggers itself if the device is not mobile, therefore serving one version of the website for mobile and one for desktop.

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
      }else
        {
        $('#slider-desktop').load('http://studio24-24.com/desktop.html');
        }
      });
      </script>
```

That works fine. However, I just realized that if someone comes onto my website through http://www.website.com or www.website.com and not http://website.com, it doesnt load that part of the website?

[Website with http://](http://studio24-24.com) 
[Website with http://www](http://www.studio24-24.com)

So I have figured the cause issue. 
The issue is that http://www requires that the url in the .load(), is with http://www too. and www with www. Because in the .load there is http://mywebsite, the website only loads it when we access it with http://mywebsite.com.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

That's because `load` uses ajax, which is limited by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). `http://studio24-24.com` and `http://www.studio24-24.com` are *different* origins, so ajax between them is disallowed by default.

This is one of the reasons to use relative URLs. In your case either `"./desktop.html"` (load `desktop.html` from the same "directory" as the current page) or `"/desktop.html"` (load it from the root, even if we're in a "subdirectory").

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was just figuring out, but I didn't know how to fix it! So simple.